# DataContext accessed after Dispose in render pages/controls

Tags: c#, database, linq, dispose, lifecycle

I'm randomly getting "DataContext accessed after Dispose" errors but only on aspx and ascx pages/controls.  Is there a general rule that I shouldn't be calling methods inline on pages that use datacontexts?

I'm presuming by the time the page renders and calls the method the datacontext has already been disposed?

e.g. on default.aspx

```
<%= CurrentContent.GetText("Intro") %>
```

CurrentContent is actually a database object referred to in default.aspx.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using it like this

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    return from r in ctx.Table select r;
}
```

Deferred execution is what is happening to you.  That query does not execute right then and there, and is only running when the returned enumerator is finally used - which in this case, is after the using block disposes of your context.  If you want to be sure this doesn't happen, either change your query pattern to

```
using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
{
    return (from r in ctx.Table select r).ToList();
}
```

or change your disposal methods.  I tend to like tying the lifetime of my context to the enclosing object, which in your case would be the ASP.NET Page object.  Make the context a member variable and dispose of it in the Page.Dispose

Comment: Great thanks wyz.  I was wondering if even though you make it a list it would take that into consideration with the using statement.  Good to see it does.  This along with some general design re-jigging seems to have resolved the issue.